# Importar dados de um TXT e jogar as posições necessarias na StringGrid

Tags: delphi, arquivo

Segue o código que desenvolvi, juntamente com o meu colega de trabalho.

```pascal
    procedure TfrmGrid.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      arq: TStringGrid;
      txt: TextFile;
      c, l, treg : integer;
      lTemp: String;
    begin
      treg := 0;
      c:=0;
      l:=0;
      AssignFile(txt, Label1.Caption);
      Reset(txt);
      while not eof(txt) do
        begin
          Readln(txt, lTemp);
          if (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E14') or (copy(ltemp, 1, 3) = 'E15') then
            inc(treg);
        end;
      while not eof(txt) do
        begin
          Readln(txt, lTemp);
          if (copy(lTemp, 1, 3)= 'E14') then
          c:= c+1;
          copy(arq[c][l],1,3);
        end;
      CloseFile(txt);

      ShowMessage('total de linhas: '+IntToStr(treg));
    end;
```

O que preciso é apenas mostrar as linhas que resgatei do TXT para informar no `TStringGrid`.

O que eu estaria errando aí?

Comment: Qual erro surgiu?

Comment: [dcc32 Error] Uni3.pas(55): E2149 Class does not have a default property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

**Primeiro**, você não cria o `TStringGrid` em tempo de execução. Crie o componente em design time.

**Segundo**, a sintaxe do comando `copy(arq[c][l],1,3);`, se eu entendi direito, está errada. Devia ser `copy(Arq.Cells[c,l],1,3);`

**Terceiro**, você não está fazendo nada com o `TStringGrid`. Nem populando, nem utilizando os dados dele. O comando copy criado por você não é atribuído a nada nem ninguém.

**Quarto**, o erro informado no comentário não tem nada a ver com a procedure (que por si só não compilaria por outros motivos) postada. O erro citado provavelmente está em outro lugar na unit.

Finalizando, segue procedure corrigida:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  txt: TextFile;
  c, l, treg : integer;
  lTemp: String;
begin
  treg := 0;
  c:=0;
  l:=1;
  AssignFile(txt, 'c:\teste.txt');
  Reset(txt);
  while not eof(txt) do
  begin
    Readln(txt, lTemp);
    if (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E14') or (copy(ltemp, 1, 3) = 'E15') then
      inc(treg);
  end;
  while not eof(txt) do
  begin
    Readln(txt, lTemp);
    if (copy(lTemp, 1, 3)= 'E14') then
      c:= c+1;
    copy(Arq.Cells[c,l],1,3); //??
  end;
  CloseFile(txt);
  ShowMessage('total de linhas: '+IntToStr(treg));
end;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado com sempre, ainda não acabei o código, mas está quase concluido. Obrigado @Filipe.Fonseca

Comment: fiz o seguinte substitui por o item em negrito por "sgCupons.Cells[0,l] := copy(lTemp,47,6);"

Comment: @DBX8 se a sua edição tornou o post exatamente como estava no começo, não seria mais interessante reverter para a versão 1?